# How can I get value of radio button's input?

Tags: python, html, django

How can I get the value of an input? I wrote the code in HTML,

```
<form action="{% url 'app:top' %}" method="POST">
              <input type="radio" name="no" value="1">
              <label>No</label>
              <input type="radio" name="yes" value="1">
              <label>Yes</label>
<input class="disabled" type="submit" value="POST">
</form>
```

in `views.py`;

```
def top(request):
    no = request.POST.get("no","0")
    yes = request.POST.get("yes","0")

    print(no)
    print(yes)
```

When I No label and put send button, 0 is printed. Putting Yes button is same. Why does it happens? Why can't I print out 1? How should I do it?

Comment: A radio input is only successful if checked - if not it's not submitted. Also, one generally group radio buttons by name - your radio should have the same name but different values - so only one out of the group can be selected at a time (if you want individual distinct choices use checkboxes instead). And finally, I fail to see how you can submit your form with the submit deactivated.

Comment: This being said you'd be better using django forms instead of manually coding everything.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="{% url 'app:top' %}" method="POST">
          <input type="radio" name="answer" value="no">
          <label>No</label>
          <input type="radio" name="answer" value="yes">
          <label>Yes</label>
<input type="submit" value="POST">
</form>
```

In `views.py`

```
def top(request):
    answer = request.POST.get('answer')
    print(answer)
```